# What woes a writer wrought

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> What ill fate I suffer from today!
> Really, it has caused me some delay.
>
> I cannot bear to see my works suffer,
> 'Tis the most awful, writing is tougher.
>
> I am laughed at when I present my novel,
> Now that I see it, a problem most awful.
>
> Goes without saying, that I am no good at this,
> So many things wrong with it, my words always miss.

What problem am I suffering from?

Hint:

> Perhaps I should emphasize, my words are all wrong.
> Really there is no doubt, my writing is not strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you suffering from

> [MALAPROPISMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism), using an *incoherent* but similar sounding word to the correct word?

What ill fate I suffer from today! 
Really, it has caused me some delay.

> If people struggle to come up with the right words, they might be *deluded* by selecting words that sound similar.

I cannot bear to see my works suffer, 
'Tis the most awful, writing is tougher.

> Using the wrong words would make your works *sulfur*.

I am laughed at when I present my novel, 
Now that I see it, a problem most awful.

> This often works to *cosmetic* effect; Stan Hardy and Archie Bunker both used malapropisms to garner laughs (although this is bad if it's not the intended purpose!)

Goes without saying, that I am no good at this, 
So many things wrong with it, my words always miss.

> Well, at least you're not *flamingo* dancing!

Perhaps I should emphasize, my words are all wrong. 
Really there is no doubt, my writing is not strong.

> Malapropisms literally mean using the wrong word; but I won't mention it because I am the *pineapple* of politeness!

Comment: 'Tis a binder to see my writhings go so wrung. These malapropriations have cussed much sparrow. Gouda job for fingering it out.

Comment: Always glade to land a hind!

Comment: On a side note, my prose is horrendous on first drafts, (which is why I came up with this puzzle). Writing these riddles daily allows me to practice my prose and avoid your answer, though I still make bundles.

Comment: Ah I see; good for you for using the puzzles to make improvements in your writing; without this puzzle or comment thread, I'd never have known.

Answer (score 1):

Are you suffering from

> Writer's Block? (which is weird, because these puzzles are so well written I find that hard to believe!!)

What ill fate I suffer from today! 
Really, it has caused me some delay.

> Delay, because you can't think of words to write.

I cannot bear to see my works suffer, 
'Tis the most awful, writing is tougher.

> It's really tough to write and write without delay, and still have the work turn out to be good.

I am laughed at when I present my novel, 
Now that I see it, a problem most awful.

> Trying to push through writer's block can mean subpar work.

Goes without saying, that I am no good at this, 
So many things wrong with it, my words always miss.

> Writer's block can leave you with holes in the story, or continuity problems, or no way to move the plot forward.

And secret hints:

> Your acrostic-du-jour spells WRITINGS, definitely keeping with the theme of the puzzle!

Comment: 'Tis not this problem, from which I suffer, but a guess most appropriate. Many writers fail like I do, with this problem which causes emotions to abate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you suffering from

> Boring Writing? (Perhaps over-verbosity or rambling or unconcise writing?)

What ill fate I suffer from today! 
Really, it has caused me some delay.

> Delay, because you take too long to get your message across if you're rambling.

I cannot bear to see my works suffer, 
'Tis the most awful, writing is tougher.

> It's hard to compose concise pieces of writing.

I am laughed at when I present my novel, 
Now that I see it, a problem most awful.

> It's so *long* and boring to read because you ramble.

Goes without saying, that I am no good at this, 
So many things wrong with it, my words always miss.

> [*Why waste time say lot word, when few word do trick?*](https://tenor.com/view/the-office-brian-baumgartner-kevin-malone-few-words-waste-time-gif-4759685)

And secret hints:

> Your acrostic-du-jour spells WRITINGS, definitely keeping with the theme of the puzzle! This problem also causes emotions to abate because people spend too much time thinking about the words and not enough time thinking about the story.

Comment: An answer much closer, to the one I'm looking for. Alas, the answer is more specific, a word that makes writers everywhere sore.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that came to my mind was

> Writer's Anxiety

What ill fate I suffer from today!
Really, it has caused me some delay.

> People with anxiety always think something bad is going to happen. They also delay things of which they think might cause harm.

I cannot bear to see my works suffer,
'Tis the most awful, writing is tougher.

> people with writer's anxiety will doubt what they wrote down and keep rewriting it even though it was good the first time.

I am laughed at when I present my novel,
Now that I see it, a problem most awful.

> They commonly think that other people are always laughing with them and that they will criticize them. If 10 people say it's good and 1 says it's not they commonly go with the one that's not and start viewing it from their point of view.

Goes without saying, that I am no good at this,
So many things wrong with it, my words always miss.

> Most of the time they think that what they do is never good enough and they will say and think that they are just not good at what they do